# The includes file does not work when the previous section is hidden

Tags: php, include

includes("includes/footer.php");

This works perfectly when I have the previous section set to visible. In other words, the rendered page correctly shows the footer.

```
<section class="visible">
content here
</section>

<?php
includes("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

BUT when the previous section is set to hidden the footer also disappears (it is not inside the section)

```
<section class="hidden">
content here
</section>

<?php
includes("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

The page does not render to include the footer. I can't understand why.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

GH

Comment: How are the classes visible and hidden defined? What is the content of footer.php?

Comment: They are defined using the d-none class of bootstrap.

Comment: The footer is just a navigation bar with links - nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: You probably have some sort of HTML tag nesting error there, so that your footer element does not actually come after the section, but is located _inside_ of it.

Comment: The footer is at the very end after the closing </section> tag of the HTML.